# Create buttons in HTML to update

Tags: html, button, web

i'm creating two html pages : update and index
in update page:
i want to create a button CHOOSE FILE to choose an image.
and another button SAVE to insert the image file in index page.
how can i create these two button.

```html
<div class="slides"> 
<li data-bg-image="images/slides/img1.jpg">
<div class="container"> 
<div class="slide-content"> 
<!--<small class="slide-sub and for the button 
<button type="button" onclick="chooseFile();">choose file</button> 
<textarea id="textarea1" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea> 
<div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden"> 
<input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" onchange="this.form.filename.value = this.value"/> 
</div
```

Comment: Please post any code you have so far, and let us know exactly what issues you ran into. We can't write code for you, but we can take a look at something you already have started and help troubleshoot.

Comment: i implement for images: <div class="slides">
     <li data-bg-image="images/slides/img1.jpg">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="slide-content">
        <!--<small class="slide-sub and for the button   <button type="button" onclick="chooseFile();">choose file</button>
      <textarea id="textarea1" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>
    <div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden">
    
    
   <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput"  onchange="this.form.filename.value = this.value"/>

    </div>

Comment: Did you mean for part of that code to be commented out? Please also edit your question to include that code. Thanks.

Comment: i am new and i want to create a page that shows photos. and another page let to choose the photos

Comment: ok, but the code in your question outputs one bullet point and nothing else. Is that what you meant it to do? Maybe you want to delete these characters: `<!--` in the 5th line, and add a final `>` at the very end to close the last tag.

Comment: Like this? `<div class="slides"> 
<li data-bg-image="images/slides/img1.jpg">
<div class="container"> 
<div class="slide-content"> 
<small class="slide-sub">
<button type="button" onclick="chooseFile();">choose file</button> 
<textarea id="textarea1" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea> 
<div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden"> 
<input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" onchange="this.form.filename.value = this.value"/> 
</div>`

Comment: yes this my code

Comment: Did you try running the snippet in the question? There are a few small differences between the code you posted and the version I put in my comment. It is not your exact code.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `input` and `submit` template for input is :

```
<input accept="file_extension|audio/*|video/*|image/*|media_type">
```

For example:

```html
<form action="/upload_image.php">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: what you mean by /*

Comment: File types that you accept. In this case accepting all file extensions.e.g: `.gif, .jpg, .png, .doc ` instead of separately `*` is used here.

Comment: ok great. i wrote this code in page2. how can i update image img11 in page 1 when i press on submit button

Comment: You have to change url of current image into your uploaded image url.

Comment: PAGE1:<div class="hero">
    <div class="slides">
     <li data-bg-image="images/slides/img1.jpg">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="slide-content">

      </div>
     </li>

     <li data-bg-image="images/slides/img2.jpg">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="slide-content">

      </div>
     </li>
    </div>
   </div>

Comment: <input accept="file_extension|audio/*|video/*|image/*|media_type">
<form action="/upload_image.php">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

PAGE2

Comment: You are going to off-topic. Do some research of how to store image after uploading it using JavaScript. For clues: You will have to change `form`  action to a JavaScript function which handles your uploaded file and saves it to you storage.